# "svnrdump" command getting "svnrdump: command not found" error

Tags: macos, svn, macos-sierra, svndump

I have installed command line tools on my macOS Sierra, but I am not able to use "svnrdump" command. It gives "svnrdump: command not found" error. Here is how my /usr/bin looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally indicates that the program you're attempting to execute doesn't exist in the `$PATH` environment variable. In your post, you said you're looking in `/usr/bin` but your screenshot clearly shows a different directory path - `CommandLineTools/usr/bin` - likely with `CommandLineTools` being the child of another directory (or multiple).

Locate the full path to `svnrdump` and run `/path/to/svnrdump` and it should work - then consider adding that path to `$PATH` so you don't have to do it all the time.